# I'm trying to negate these statements.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'd appreciate it if someone could tell me where I've gone wrong and how to fix my mistakes! The original statements to be negated are below and after are the my attempts at negations. Thank you.
1)  $∀b ∈ R, ∃x ∈ R : x^
2 − 4bx + 4b^
2 ≤ 0$

2)  $∃a ∈ Z : ∀b ∈ N, −3 > 5a − 2b$

3)  $∀S ⊆ R
2
, ∃(x, y) ∈ S : x − y = 0$

My answers are:

1) $∃b∉R:x^2-4bx+4b^2>0, ∀x∉R$

2) $∀a∉Z:∃b∉N, -3≤5a-2b$

3) $∃S⊄R^2:x-y≠0,∀(x,y)∉S $

Comment: So would the second and third become: 'there exists a belong to Z such that there exists b belong to N, -3 less than/equal to 5a-2b' and 'there exist s subset of R^2, for all (x,y) subset of S:x-y Not equal to 0'?

Comment: Yes! Now you understand it

Comment: "there exists $a$ belong to $Z$"? hmmm.... check again?

Comment: for all a belonging to Z?

Comment: yup, that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me fix the first one for you.

1)  $\forall b ∈ R, \exists x \in  R : x^
2 − 4bx + 4b^
2 \le 0$

Should become

$\exists b \color{red}{\in } R, \forall x \color{red}\in R: x^2 - 4bx + 4b^2 > 0$.

The thing is the first statement says that for all $b$, there must be some $x$ such that condition $P(x)$ is not true.

To negate the statement, that is to show that the statement is false, we need a counter example from $R$, hence $\exists b \in R$ that the property doesn't hold for all the $x$ in $R$.

Answer (score 0):

Your principal problem is with the negation of memberships of sets, which is not needed and wrong.

In general:

- The negation of "for all $a\in R$ happens P" is "there exists at least one $a\in R$ for which P does not happen".
- The negation of "there is at least one $a\in R$ such that P happens" is "there is no $a\in R$ for which P happens", which would be positively translated into "for all $a\in R$, P does not happen".

With this in mind you should be able to complete your task.